# Картина Репина "Приплыли"

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> — У меня нет денег.
>    — *Картина Репина "Приплыли"*... Почему ты раньше не сказал об этом?

Выделенное курсивом предложение — назывное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ изменен

Фактически эта фраза является следующей реакцией  на увиденное или услышанное: **Вот так приплыли!** (Это если не упоминать картину, а говорить только о ее содержании).

Фразеологический оборот является идиомой со значением оценки. Его можно отнести **к междометным фразеологизмам.**

Этот класс выражений является малоизученным. По мнению некоторых ученых, междометные обороты различной структуры обладают **номинативной функцией,** а их денотация проявляется в соотнесенности оборота с конкретной ситуацией в каждом случае.

Хотя заданное предложение – это структура **назывного вида**, но его вряд ли можно классифицировать как неполное или назывное предложение.

Те же эмоции может выразить целый ряд слов, словосочетаний или предложений, например: *Нормально! Ну ты даешь! Интересное кино.*

О междометных фразеологических единицах: [http://pglu.ru/upload/iblock/62a/statya-*22*.pdf](http://pglu.ru/upload/iblock/62a/statya-_22_.pdf)

Происхождение фразеологизма: http://www.inqui.ru/2018/07/kartina-repina-priplyli.html

Answer (score 2):

Склонна считать, что это выражение по функции сродни междометию, ср.:

***" У меня нет денег".
— "[Вот те раз!]... Почему ты раньше не сказал об этом?"***

Междометие – это особая неизменяемая часть речи, не относящаяся ни к знаменательным частям речи, ни к служебным, которая служит для непосредственного *выражения эмоций, чувств, волеизъявлений, призывов, не называя их.*

В. В. Виноградов отмечал, что междометия очень часто представляют собой "целостные высказывания", "предложения", "эквиваленты предложений": *Ах! Слава Богу! и пр.*

В процессе развития языка в разряд междометий перешли отдельные фразеологизмы: *Боже мой! Батюшки-светы! Дело – табак! Черт возьми!* и др. [Междометие. Современный русский язык](https://studme.org/56362/literatura/mezhdometie)

Comment: По смыслу  эта фраза может быть междометием, но речь идет о грамматике. Мы имеем  структуру назывного типа с оценочным значением, как определить ее грамматический вид. Междометные фразеологизмы могут иметь структуру предложений, например: "Вот тебе, бабушка, и Юрьев день".  Междометие выражает разочарование, но с точки зрения грамматики это определенный вид двусоставного предложения.

Comment: Очень рада, что Вы пересмотрели свою позицию и изменили  ответ.

Comment: Ну да, мне пересмотреть позицию - это очень легко. Появилась какая-то идея, которую можно использовать,  она навела меня на мысль, что не стоит рассматривать данную фразу в рамках назывное/неполное предложение.  Обычно считают, что я заимствую чужие идеи, не указывая на автора, но я их никогда не копирую, я только использую. Поэтому спасибо Вам за идею,  но позиция у меня моя собственная, не взятая со стороны.

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКаштанова Катя (можно?),  я ― с Вами!